# How to not display environment variable in org-babel src block?

Tags: org-babel, environment

I want the effect of this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :dir src
CC=gcc-9 make
#+END_SRC
```

But I don't want `CC=gcc-9` to show up in the output.

Is there a way to somehow include the environment variable in the `BEGIN_SRC` header?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :dir src :env "CC=gcc-9"
make
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Instead of `:env "CC=gcc-9"` header have you tried using `:var CC="gcc-9"` header?

Comment: @Melioratus: he needs to have it exported to the environment in order for the Makefile to pick it up - a plain :var does not do that (AFAIK).

Comment: If you don't mind adding it to the environment "permanently", you can do `:eval (setenv "CC' "gcc-9")`.

Comment: @NickD how "permanently" are we talking?

Comment: @NickD - Very good point, thank you! You are completely correct, the `:var` header does not add the `export` keyword in front of the variables when a code block is rendered! I’d completely forgotten that was the case. Thanks again!

Comment: Try adding `:prologue "export CC=\"gcc-9\""` header. Just rendering this and it appears to work when code block is rendered.

Comment: It adds it to the environment of the emacs process, so it will be in the environment of any process that the emacs process spawns, i.e. till that emacs instance dies; unless you "unset" it by hand: `(setenv "CC" "")`  - this does not really unset it: it's still in the environment with an empty value, but it's close enough for most work.